# Grap imdb ratings

Tags: php, imdb

I'm trying to use this simple get_data code:

https://davidwalsh.name/php-imdb-information-grabber

but I don't know how to get rating points. E.g. 7.4 (I want to leave stars and voters etc off)

I have trying this but it shows all results, title, plot etc... (Not working correctly).

```
 $ratings = get_match('/<div class="ratingValue">(.*?)<\/div>/isU',$imdb_content);
```

Comment: what's in $imdb_content?

Comment: That link is from 2008, imdb probably changed layout since then

Comment: Just look at the HTML and you'll see where the value is you need: `<span itemprop="ratingValue">7.9</span>`. You know most browsers have a build in function, right click on the element and select "inspect". Also IMDB most certainly has a proper API toget data like that.

Comment: @kerbholz which is an excellent example of why screen-scraping data from HTML is rarely a great idea :-)